# Alterar foreground color no binding do XAML (não funcionando)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

Tenho um texto que a cor deveria alternar de acordo com a verificação do metodo abaixo:

```
public Color VerificaAlarmes
            {
                get => ChecarLimites? AlarmColors: Color.Gold;
            }

            public Color AlarmColors
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Value > AltoAlm)
                        return Color.Red;
                    else if (Value < BaixoAlm)
                        return Color.Green;
                    else
                        return Color.Gold;
                }
            }
```

Este é o binding no texto no XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Descrição}"
                                           Foreground="{Binding VerificaAlarmes}" 
                                           FontSize="18"
                                           FontWeight="Semibold" />
```

Coloquei o Color sendo tipo System.Drawing.Color só que as cores não eram retornadas. Depois coloquei o color sendo System.Windows.Media.Brushes e nao funcionou também, os retornos das cores ainda não acontecem.

Answer (score 1):

É provável que o valor esteja sendo alterado, porém pela falta de notificação, a UI não está sendo atualizada, tente implementar a interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged).

Segue um exemplo:

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="thisWindow"
        DataContext="{x:Reference thisWindow}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Valor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10"  />

        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding VerificaAlarmes}"  Margin="10" />

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _valor = 50;

    public int Valor
    {
        get => _valor;
        set
        {
            if (value == _valor) return;
            _valor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VerificaAlarmes));
        }
    }

    public Brush VerificaAlarmes => AlarmColors;

    public Brush AlarmColors
    {
        get
        {
            if (Valor > 75)
                return Brushes.Red;
            else if (Valor < 25)
                return Brushes.Green;
            else
                return Brushes.Gold;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```